# Deleting unwanted contacts from my cloud

Tags: contacts, sync, google-account

I lost my S3 Mini and all my phone numbers were backed up on Google cloud. When I activated my Moto G and downloaded all my numbers, some of the ones that showed up on my phone were numbers that were unlisted or private and names popped up in my contact list.

I deleted them from my contact list on my phone, but when it backs up and re-syncs, the numbers that I had deleted from my phone show up again. I need to delete them from my cloud, but I can't find them in my Google account, and my Gmail only shows email contacts, not from my phone.

How to delete unwanted contacts from my Google cloud?

Comment: In the Settings within your Contacts/People app, there should be there should be a way to toggle which contacts to display. Pick the option to display contacts from all accounts/locations i.e. Phone, SIM, Google accounts etc. and delete any unwanted contacts. All unwanted contacts should be gone. You can then again toggle which location/account you want your contacts list to be populated from.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit your contacts via web interface, you can do this at https://contacts.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

The person who picked up your phone is probably still using it. Delete all unnecessary contacts and afterward, immediately change your Google password and log out from all devices for once.